# How to based in a condition apply or not a property into a jsx element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this element:

`<div id="app-wrapper" style={{"grid-template-columns": "50% 50%"}}>..</div>`

I want to based on a condition defined in my component's state change the style property to this:

`<div id="app-wrapper" style={{"grid-template-columns": "100%"}}>..</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You like to use ternary operators:

```
<div id="app-wrapper" style={{"grid-template-columns": condition?"100%":"50% 50%"}}>..</div>
```

Comment: It throws me a SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'this' <div id="app-wrapper" style={{"grid-template-columns": {this.state.maximizedWindow === NONE?"100%":"50% 50%"}}}>

Comment: yes but it has nothing to do with the answer here. its about your state and it depends on your context whether this is defined or not. if your state gets updated in a class member method you have to make sure to bind this to the member.

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally render the style using a ternary operator in 2 ways:

**Option 1:**

```
<div id="app-wrapper" style={state? {"grid-template-columns": "50% 50%"} : {"grid-template-columns": "100%"}}>..</div>
```

**Option 2 (cleaner):**

```
const divStyle = state? {"grid-template-columns": "50% 50%"} : {"grid-template-columns": "100%"}


<div id="app-wrapper" style={divStyle}>..</div>
```

Comment: It throws me a SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'this' <div id="app-wrapper" style={{"grid-template-columns": {this.state.maximizedWindow === NONE?"100%":"50% 50%"}}}>